# Can I develop for Android without an Android studio? i don't have a I3 processor to do android programming

Tags: android, android-studio

Can I develop for Android without an Android studio? i don't have a I3 processor to do android programming. is there any other option if i don't want to use any online compilers?

Comment: I think that you can compile the project only with gradle and without IDE but I am not 100% sure. Another option would be for you to try Qt for Android, here I am sure you can program without IDE.

Comment: depends on what You want do develop. 'Hello World' is possible...Develop an app without an IDE, I wouldn't recomment

Comment: You can, in fact, compile with just gradle and the Android Gradle Plugin.  No IDE needed.

Comment: Where does this "I3 processor" requirement come from? Do they state that you need Intel i3? Older versions of Android Studio are also available, so you don't need to use the latest and greatest version.